# CSS Resizing background image height

Tags: css, background

I am making a website where the background is resizing when the window is resized. When i change te width of the window it just works fine. But when i resize the height of the window it doesnt resize. Here is what i mean:

[image]

Here is my CSS code:

```
body{
font-family: Georgia;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
margin-top: -16px;
padding: 0;
background-image:url('back.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I have tried doing `background-size: 100%;`, but that didnt really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the **html** property instead of **body** because its always at minimum the size of the browser height.

The below code should help you achieve the 100% width 100% height background (even on resize). Depending on your project, I would recommending adding the vendor prefixes for maximum compatibility.

```
     html{
        background:url('back.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;

     }
```